# Как сделать скролл наподобие вконтакте в группах для правого меню

Tags: html, jquery, css, css3, html5

```js
 var alt_top=top=0;
var left;
// высота блока с меню, px
var h_nav =$('#menu_left').height();
//высота экрана
var windows_height=$(window).height();
//высота контента
var h_content=$("main").outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    alt_top=top;
    top = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(alt_top+":"+top);

   
    if (h_nav>windows_height) {
        if (top+windows_height >= h_nav && alt_top<=top) {
            if (h_nav<h_content)
                $("#menu_left").addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            //идем наверх
            if ($("#menu_left").hasClass("fixed"))
                $("#menu_left").removeClass("fixed");
        }
    }else{
        //+
        $("#menu_left").addClass("fixed").css("top","0px");
    }
});
```

Пример группы вконтакте https://vk.com/public79858706
что сделать для обратного плавного скролла вверх...

Comment: я не понял вопрос какой скролл?

Comment: Делаем скролл, а перед отрисовкой вставляем замедление или что-то типа.

Comment: @Избытоксусликов,пример скролла правого меню , как вконтакте, но, в обратную сторону....Пример группы вконтакте https://vk.com/public79858706

Comment: @RomanC,рисовать скролл не надо, нужно, сделать наподобие правого меню вконтакте, ко7гда оно скролится (вниз нормально работает, только в обратную не очень плавно....)